# RGBDSLAMv2 missing siftgpu library error

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rgbdslamv2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
My system is Ubuntu 12.04. In the 3rd step of the installation instructions, a get an error about the missing siftgpu library. I execute "catkin_make" command again but I'm still having same problem;

...

[ 67%] Building CXX object rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/header.o

[ 69%] Building CXX object rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/sift_gpu_wrapper.o

Linking CXX executable /home/oguzhan/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/devel/lib/rgbdslam/rgbdslam

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsiftgpu

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make[2]: *** [/home/oguzhan/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/devel/lib/rgbdslam/rgbdslam] Error 1

make[1]: *** [rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/all] Error 2

make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed

***second make:***

oguzhan@ubuntu:~/rgbdslam_catkin_ws$ catkin_make

Base path: /home/oguzhan/rgbdslam_catkin_ws

Source space: /home/oguzhan/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src

Build space: /home/oguzhan/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/build

Devel space: /home/oguzhan/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/devel

Install space: /home/oguzhan/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/install

Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/oguzhan/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/build"

Running command: "make -j1 -l1" in "/home/oguzhan/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/build"

[  7%] Built target rgbdslam_generate_messages_cpp

[  7%] Built target rgbdslam_gencpp

Linking CXX executable /home/oguzhan/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/devel/lib/rgbdslam/rgbdslam

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsiftgpu

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make[2]: *** [/home/oguzhan/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/devel/lib/rgbdslam/rgbdslam] Error 1

make[1]: *** [rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/all] Error 2

make: *** [all] Error 2

Invoking "make" failed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182812/rgbdslamv2-missing-siftgpu-library-error/) by [Oguzhan Pierre](https://answers.ros.org/users/19429/oguzhan-pierre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-07-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2014-07-07**:
Is SiftGPU built? Do you have the file ../src/rgbdslam/external/SiftGPU/bin/libsiftgpu.so (within the rgbdslam package directory)? Otherwise try executing make in ../src/rgbdslam/external/SiftGPU/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it works thanks FELIX
under ubuntu 14.04 and ROS indigo.

---

Originally posted by [bleuscreen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25123/bleuscreen/) with karma: 36 on 2016-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0